# VBA: Colocar um espaço antes ou depois de letras maiúsculas em um determinado texto

Tags: string, microsoft-excel, funções, vba, texto

Tenho uma sequência de textos que representam nomes de clientes, mas que estão sem os devidos espaçoes entre cada palavra/nome (por exemplo: *CarlosAlbertoGomes*). Contudo as palavras podem ser diferenciadas pois a primeira letra de cada palavra está maiúscula.

Precisava transpor essa lista de clientes para seus nomes regulares, com espaços entre cada palavra, ou seja, *CarlosAlbertoGomes* passará a ser *Carlos Alberto Gomes*. Contudo, não consegui pensar em nenhuma maneira imediata de conseguir isso e acredito que nenhuma combinação de fórmulas do Excel oferece isso de maneira nativa.

Assim, acredito que a única solução seria apelar para a programação VBA, ou de uma função para ser utilizada como fórmula, ou de uma Macro em módulo para rodar sobre determinado intervalo (suponhamos que meu texto se encontra no `Range("A2:A100")`).

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei essa função em `VBA` para você:

Ela vai verificar se cada letra no nome está em maiúsculo. Em caso afirmativo, vai adicionar um espaço antes da letra em questão.

**Código:**

```
Function separa_nomes(str As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer, temp As String

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If i = 1 Then
            temp = Mid(str, i, 1)
        ElseIf Mid(str, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
            temp = temp + " " + Mid(str, i, 1)
        Else
            temp = temp + Mid(str, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    separa_nomes = temp

End Function
```

---

Para habilitá-la, basta abrir o `VBE`, `inserir um novo módulo` e c`olar esse código` na janela aberta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após inserir o código, a função `=separa_nomes()` vai poder ser utilizada nas suas planilhas.

**Ex.:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**EDIT:** Como é o funcionamento desse código?

- A ideia é criar uma função que conte quantos caracteres cada palavra tem

  - `Len(str)`
- Faça um loop indo letra por letra

  - `For i = 1 To Len(str)`
- Se a letra encontrada for a primeira letra da palavra: salvo a letra numa variável chamada `temp` e não coloco espaço antes.

  - `If i = 1 Then temp = Mid(str, i, 1)`
- Se a letra encontrada for maiúscula: isso significa que preciso colocar um espaço antes dela na hora de guardá-la na variável `temp`.

  - `ElseIf Mid(str, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then temp = temp + " " + Mid(str, i, 1)`
- Caso contrario: só copio a letra para a variável `temp`, sem adicionar nenhum espaço.

  - `Else temp = temp + Mid(str, i, 1)`
- Por fim, mostro o resultado acumulado na variável `temp` na célula onde a fórmula foi chamada.

  - `separa_nomes = temp`

---

Ou seja, para alterar a posição do espaço quando encontrar uma letra maiúscula (de antes para depois da letra em maiúsculo), você deve alterar o termo:

De:

```
ElseIf Mid(str, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
    temp = temp + " " + Mid(str, i, 1)
```

Para:

```
ElseIf Mid(str, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
    temp = temp + Mid(str, i, 1) + " "
```

Comment: Muito legal! Funcionou certinho!

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar! :-)

Comment: Tentei dissecar o código mas não conseguideduzir quais adaptações eu poderia fazer caso eu quisesse adicionar o espaço DEPOIS da letra maiúsula. Você poderia adicionar essa função em sua resposta?

Comment: @Tash_Riser editei meu post e dei uma explicada na função. Veja se melhorou o seu entendimento...